# How does the Hail of Doom weapon trait work on each of the Beam Staff's attack types?

Tags: warhammer-vermintide

A weapon with the Hail of Doom trait is described as:

> Each shot with this weapon has a 5.0 - 15.0% chance to split into 2
>   projectiles.

Does this proc with each of the Beam Staff's different attack types? These are: primary (shotgun-like blast), secondary (beam attack), and the attack done when you press primary fire while holding secondary fire (high damage on beamed target).

I'm especially curious if it procs with the beam attack and how does it proc. (Two beams or two 'ticks' instead of one?)

Answer (score 1):

It only works with beam explosion (primary fire with beamed target).

https://steamcommunity.com/app/235540/discussions/1/1290690926876256733/

HoD consumes double ammo/generates double heat when it procs, if you want to verify yourself.